# Django ORM update_or_create() case sensitivity

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

## Problem Description

I have a model called `SourceData` that looks like this:

```
class SourceData(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(DataSourceStatus, null=True, default=True, related_name='source_data')
    sessions = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
    bounce_rate = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
    goal_completions_all = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
    goal_conversion_rate_all = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
    transactions = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
    transaction_revenue = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
    data_date = models.DateField()
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When I try to populate it, I iterate through a list of records which are dictionary objects, each with a case-sensitive `source` field. Sometimes these `source` fields will look like `Master List` or `MASTER LIST` and I want to preserve the casing.

Here is my population method:

```
source_data, created = SourceData.objects.update_or_create(
    seller=data_source_status,
    data_date=date_record,
    source__exact=sub.get('source', ' '),
    defaults={
        'seller': data_source_status,
        'data_date': date_record,
        'sessions': sub.get('sessions', 0),
        'bounce_rate': sub.get('bounceRate', 0),
        'goal_completions_all': sub.get('goalCompletionsAll', 0),
        'goal_conversion_rate_all': sub.get('goalConversionRateAll', 0),
        'transactions': sub.get('transactions', 0),
        'transaction_revenue': sub.get('transactionRevenue', 0),
        'source': sub.get('source', ' '),
    }
)
```

After looking through much documentation and StackOverflow articles, I added `__eexact` to the `source` param, which I believed would require the string to be EXACTLY what I retrieved for it to update the record. This is not what is actually happening however. `Master List` is overwritten by `MASTER LIST`...

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

**Update:** I updated the code to use `__exact` and STILL having records overwritten by other keys...

Comment: No, `__iexact` means *incasesensitive* (that where the `i` originates from).

Comment: Damn... well before it case insensitive too... I thought iexact meant IS EXACT.